# jQuery "Options" tab style plugin

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, accordion

I would love to have a plugin or some script that recreates the tool that jQuery uses to display the options for their UI plugins. This is kind of like the accordion but with much less bulkiness and the ability to keep multiple tabs open at once.

If you go to this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/, and click on the options tab you'll see what I mean by an accordion type object that displays information about each option when the arrow is clicked. Thank you so much to anyone who can find/make a plugin/tool like this! I've searched for a few hours now without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing more than a toggle that hides/shows when the arrow is clicked.

Check out the code on this page. It should give you an idea of how to build it out. Quite simple, really! http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/02/more-showing-more-hiding

Comment: You know, for some reason .toggle() just flew right by me, thanks for pointing this out! Should be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I made an example for you. You should write your own code for this. It would be a great exercise.

[example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWvQs/)